# What did Asimov find embarrassing about "Marooned Off Vesta”?

Tags: short-stories, isaac-asimov

I have been looking through “The Early Asimov Volume 1”. The first story that Asimov published was “Marooned off Vesta”, published in 1939 in Amazing Stories when Asimov was nineteen years old.

Although it is not actually included in the book, he gives a brief description of how it came to be published. He also includes the commentary that the magazine “contains a little autobiographical squib in the rear, written by my teen-age self. On rereading, years later, it turned out to be exquisitely embarrassing".

What was so embarrassing?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I believe that the embarrassment is from the [autobiographical snippets provided by the authors at the end of the magazine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViI0D.png), rather than over the story itself. There are two sentences which might be thought of as “embarrassing.”

The first is when Asimov describes his personal appearance, and remarks “*my mother thinks I’m handsome*.” But I think the phrase in question is *“As far as I know I have no vices - or, at least, no serious vices*.” When he wrote this Asimov was only eighteen years old, and it contrasts rather heavily with the “Lecherous Old Man” stereotype he played up in later years.

> ISAAC ASIMOV
> Author of MAROONED OFF VESTA
>
> BY the time these words see print I shall be an aged patriarch rapidly approaching the venerable age of nineteen. Of these nineteen the last ten have been spent mainly in, on and about science fiction.
>
> As a matter of fact, my father introduced me to my first copy of AMAZING some time in 1929 and the first story I read was “Barton’s Island.” Since then, I have been a steady reader, my favorite story of all time being “Drums of Tapajos.”
>
> I am of medium height, dark, and my mother thinks I’m handsome. The general consensus of opinion does not commit itself quite so far, but I do not complain. I am now serving the last year of my sentence at Columbia University and will graduate next June with flying colors.
>
> My favorite pastime is reading; my favorite sciences, mathematics and astronomy (though I major in chemistry at Columbia and am taking a pre-medical course). Also, I like cats. As far as I know, I have no vices—or, at least, no serious vices. And, oh yes, I like to write.
>
> My first attempt at writing came at twelve but the monstrosity that resulted has been burned long ago. Science fiction did not come until I had acquired my first typewriter four years ago, but it was not until the middle of 1938 that I took my life in my hands and bearded the mighty Editor in his den. The Providence that watches over the rash beamed kindly down upon me and “Marooned Off Vesta” is the result.
>
> It may be unusual but I don’t know exactly how I got the idea for the story; like Topsy, it just growed.
>
> There are more stories on the way, some in a state of partial completion now, and I hope and hope again, that this first story does not prove to be a flash in the pan. If it does, it won’t be because I didn't try.
>
> Anyway, I hope you like the story. After all, it is the readers that are the powers behind the throne and they must be pleased.
>
> Au revoir until we meet again; and I sincerely hope we will.
> —Isaac Asimov, Brooklyn, N, Y.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of transcribing the snippet.

Comment: I wouldn't choose those two sentences as the embarrassing ones :-). There is plenty in there for an actual adult to squirm over.

Comment: Much of it seems very juvenile, but cute. I suspect that's what embarrassed him in his later years. He may also have been exaggerating the embarrassment -- he could hardly be surprised that a 19-year-old would have written like this.

Comment: @Barmar To be honest a lot of things done by teenagers are typically very embarrassing, but he had it recorded and became famous, so almost 100 years later, almost 30 years after his death, we're still reading about it... I can't think of something even more embarrassing than having your past being exposed like this.

Comment: @Nelson Indeed. We can't all be Anne Frank, having our teenage musings turn into classic reading.

Comment: @Nelson We are in the social network zero-privacy era; this will soon become the new normal.

Comment: If it weren't so well written it might be less funny. It is a nearly perfect imitation of the way a mature man in a 19-century adventure story talks when he is speaking as the narrator. He could almost be Dr. Watson or Allen Quatermain. It perfectly captures the awkwardness and self-consciousness of someone just putting childhood behind him and striving to assume the role of a mature man.

Comment: "There are more stories on the way" talk about a prophetic understatement...

Comment: @Barmar I'm pretty sure Anne Frank would be embarrassed by quite a few things in her diary.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Serves me right for saying that when I haven't actually read the book :)

Comment: Hi @DavidW, I've seen your edits. Could you suggest a way to indent the first line of a paragraph without resorting to HTML markup ?

Comment: @HakanÇelikMK1 I'm pretty sure that's not possible.  Note that web writing is different than print; in print the indent is used to signal paragraphs because (to save paper) paragraph spacing (vertical whitespace before a paragraph) is not used.  On the computer we have effectively infinite vertical space, and with scrolling the gap between paragraphs is necessary for readers to track where they are.  So the layout _is_ different, but it's intentionally so, and you shouldn't try to replicate print layout on the screen.

Comment: @DavidW I beg to differ on the point that, web writing is inherently different than print. There are well established rules for formatting documents and the medium is quite irrelevant. Text should look similar whether it is on a page of one of my beloved books or on screen. I'm already spending inordinate time on reading/writing computer code and I find malformed "human" text unpleasant to read. We'll have to agree to disagree on this one, I guess.

Comment: @HakanÇelikMK1 If it's any consolation, I don't like change either, and I had to adapt to online styles.  But the point remains that people with way more expertise than I actually _studied_ these things (using eye-tracking studies, for instance) to determine the best way to lay out text for reading online.  And then tools were built with input from those results, so that the defaults enforce the optimum style...  Trust me, lots of things changed moving from printed text - regular line length, reasonable hyphenation... - it's just not worth worrying about.

Comment: Maybe he's embarrassed by all the cliches, "with flying colors" etc.

Comment: @DavidW Thank you. I've been reading avidly for 43 years and I've been developing software for the last 30+ years. I've followed all the developments throughout the years; from the printed text to the current Web. I'm very good at adapting to change, actually. It's just that I don't like this particular change. It's my personal pet peeve that the language and writing should be "proper" and shouldn't be "improved" without a significant reason. You make an intriguing point, though. I'm quite interested in learning about the studies you've cited. Could you provide me some references, please ?